# UITextField starting cursor position is wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a textfield with some precompiled text. Text inside the textfield is visually right aligned. When I tap on the textfield I would like the cursor to be at the end of the text, so I can be ready to edit the text. By default the cursor is positioned at the start of the text or at the end of a word if I tap that word.

I tried to set the `selectedTextRange` property as suggested by other answers but I cannot manage to achieve the result. I noticed by the way that `becomeFirstResponder()` gives the correct behavior.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.selectedTextRange =
        textField.textRange(from: textField.endOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
}
```

[image]

Comment: except textFieldDidBeginEditing are you using any other delegate method..??

Comment: @SaifanNadaf I'm only using `textFieldShouldReturn` to dismiss the keyboard when hitting the return key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to always update your UI from the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.endOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
}
```

Comment: To clarify: IIRC, textFieldDidBeginEditing *does* execute on the main thread, but it is necessary to allow that event to complete (return from current function), *before* setting the text range. This is done by *queueing* your change to the main thread.

Comment: If I want to stick to the new async-await Task way of working, I believe the following would be an equivalent for this:

`Task { @MainActor in`
`...`
`}`