# In iOS, Cursor position is not able to update from the Started event using the "SelectedTextRange"

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uitextfield

**Description**

In iOS, not able to update the cursor position manually from the started event using the "SelectedTextRange" property on focus. Please refer to the below sample and screenshot.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Create a custom control.
2. Create native control by inheriting from UITextField.
3. Hook started the event in native.
4. Use the below code snippet to update the cursor position from the started event.
   Code Snippet:

> ```
> var positionToSet = this.GetPosition(this.BeginningOfDocument, 3);                      
> if (positionToSet != null)                                                                
> {                                                                                          
>     this.SelectedTextRange = this.GetTextRange(positionToSet, positionToSet);               
> }
> ```

```
       (OR)
```

1. Run the attached sample.
2. Cursor should be positioned in the 3rd index (next to 3) while focusing on the control.

**Expected Behavior**

The cursor should be positioned at the third index (next to 3) as shown in the below screenshot.
[image]

**Actual Behavior**

The cursor gets positioned at the last.
[image]

**Sample:**
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/7653944/CustomControl.zip

**Note:**
Issue reproduced only on or above iOS device 14.4.

Comment: updates to the UI should be made in the main thread

Comment: @LeoDabus - OP is describing code that runs on iOS.UITextView.Started event. I've tested, and Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.IsMainThread is true when this code runs. Any other idea what it could be? I've confirmed with breakpoint that SelectedTextRange is updated to (position 3, length 0) by the custom code. (on simulator, iPhone 11 iOS 15.0) Trying to think how this fails to affect the display.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to dispatch queue to the main thread before setting a range

Comment: @LeoDabus ahh right. Its on the main thread, but in middle of an action. Need to *queue* it to main thread, as you say.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61960379/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its necessary to **queue** the change so that it occurs after Started event returns:

```
CoreFoundation.DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync( () => {
    this.SelectedTextRange = this.GetTextRange(positionToSet, positionToSet);
});
```

Based on [Leo Dabus' answer in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61960379/199364).

Tested on iOS simulator, iPhone 11, iOS 15.0.

Comment: Worked +1 , invoking the code in main thread works as expected  .

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve, It is working.