# Setting the cursor to the end of a UITextField on become first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` with a text alignment set to right embedded in a `UICollectionViewCell`. If I tap the `UITextField` the cursor should be at the end of the text. Also if I tap the textfield on or before of the beginning of the text.
I tried to set the position in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method:

```swift
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let position = textField.endOfDocument
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: position, to: position)
}
```

But this didn't work so I tried it with DispatchQueue.main.async. That works. But I know, that this isn't the most elegant way and it looks like something tries to set the cursor position at the same time.

```swift
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let position = textField.endOfDocument
        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: position, to: position)
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution to set the cursor on the last position?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "most elegant way". You should always update the UI from the main thread. I don't think you have a choice here.

Comment: @LeoDabus you are right. The code above is already running in the main thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61960379/2303865